# Using struct.unpack after converting frame data from .wav file to byte object using readframes() returns an error

Tags: python, struct, wav

```
s1 = wave.open('sound.wav', 'r')
frames_1 = []
for i in range(44100):
    frames_1.append(struct.unpack('<h', s1.readframes(1)))
```

Basically, I am trying to unpack s1.readframes(1), which should return an integer value between ~-32000 and 32000. readframes() returns a byte object. It gives me the message "struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 2 bytes".

I am not sure if I am even supposed to use struct.unpack() or if there is something else that I should do. I assume I am because to write the frames to the .wav file I have to first convert the frames to bytes using data = value.writeframesraw() and then use struct.pack('<h', data), however I am not sure if I am using unpack() correctly. If I try to change '<h' to something else, it just increases the number of bytes in the error message. Optimally I want to only use the wave library for this code, but if there are other libraries that I could import that can read and write .wav files easily then please recommend them.

Comment: Strange, the very same code works fine for me, no errors at all. How many bits per sample do you have in your wav file?

Comment: @TDG params: nchannels=1, sampwidth=3, framerate=44100, nframes=12256, comptype='NONE', compname='not compressed' for one of them, nchannels=2, sampwidth=2, framerate=44100, nframes=8820, comptype='NONE', compname='not compressed' for the other one.